# Performance considerations of using subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Say, I have the below two tables

```
 ------------------------------
|           employee           |
 ------------------------------
| employee_id  | employee_name |  
 ------------------------------
|     1        |     one       |
|     2        |     two       |
|     3        |     three     |
 ------------------------------
```

and

```
 -------------------------------------------
|                feedback                   |
 -------------------------------------------
| employee_id (FK)  |       comments        |  
 -------------------------------------------
|         2         |     comment two       |
 -------------------------------------------
```

What is the best (in terms of performance) way of retrieving all employees who **have not** had their feedback given?

I was thinking of the below SQL but because it uses subquery, I am not sure how fast it will be when the number of records in both the tables grow.

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employee_id NOT IN (SELECT employee_id FROM feedback)
```

The database is Oracle and all key columns have indexes.

**Update**

Thanks everybody, I wish I could accept more than one answer! This is what I used in the end (my table structure wasn't quite as simple as shown here as I had joins with several other tables).

```
SELECT 
    e.name, m.name, a.postcode 
FROM 
    employee LEFT OUTER JOIN feedback f on (e.employee_id = f.employee_id),
    address a, manager m 
WHERE a.address_id = e.address_id
AND m.manager_id = e.manager_id
AND f.employee_id IS NULL
```

Comment: If you are familiar with explain plan then test some of the solutions below and see what the plan looks like for them: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

Comment: @Ollie I wish I could. The schema I've been given to work with doesn't have the explain plan tables. I get `SQL Error: ORA-02402: PLAN_TABLE not found.`

Comment: do you really want ALL employees with no feedback, or just the first x number of employees?

Comment: @tbone I have given a simplified example here. There are some more `WHERE` clauses added to the employee, say age, job_status, start_date and so on.

Comment: @adarshr I understand, but do u need the first, say 100 rows as quickly as possible (for displaying a page of data for example) or are you using all rows (even if millions) in some batch process.  You may have other options if the former is the case.

Comment: @tbone I see. In this particular use case, I probably won't have more than 20 records displayed to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT e.* 
  FROM employee e 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN feedback f ON (e.employee_id = f.employee_id)
 WHERE f.employee_id IS NULL
```

Which should be pretty good. I assume the EMPLOYEE_ID columns are indexed...

Try it and see what your explain plan looks like.

EDIT: As you have said you do not have the PLAN table then this article from Tom Kyte (Oracle VP) is useful:
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:313616750808

It suggests reasoning behind why each solution (`NOT IN, NOT EXISTS, OUTER JOIN`) might be better under circumstances.

There is also this from the prolific Don Burleson:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_subq_rewrite.htm

Comment: Thanks, that was spot on and those links are wicked!

Comment: I find this is really an awkward way of writing a query: in a big multi-join the JOIN clause may be far away from the WHERE clause. Modern optimizers will rewrite the query anyway so why not use the more meaningful NOT EXISTS/NOT IN ? (with the caveat of nulls with NOT IN).

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat, as you say in your comment "you" find it really awkward. Some others would not, I guess it is a personal preference, if you write it this way as a habit then it doesn't look awkward.

Comment: Agreed, and in the case of a big query i'd probably use a NOT EXISTS but this is a very small query so I used the OUTER JOIN, horses for courses etc.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly:

```
SELECT e.* FROM EMPLOYEE e
LEFT OUTER JOIN FEEDBACK f ON e.EMPLOYEE_ID = f.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE f.EMPLOYEE_ID IS NULL
```

But you can read [THIS](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/) article about it!

Comment: @adarshr sorry, you can see it now.

Comment: @aF. : Note that the article is about SQLServer while the OP asked about Oracle.

Comment: @aF, if you are using an outer join on EMPLOYEE, then joining where e.EMPLOYEE IS NULL won't get the results you need, surely it should be f.EMPLOYEE_ID IS NULL.

Comment: @MarkBannister I know but it gives him an inside of things.

Comment: i think u mean "where f.employee_id is null"

Comment: @aF, your query is STILL wrong, your WHERE clause is now "f.EMPLOYEE IS NULL" when it should read "f.EMPLOYEE_ID IS NULL". See my answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use different queries and compare theirs plans.
one more possibility to implement youe query:

```
select EMPLOYEE_ID from employee
MINUS
select EMPLOYEE_ID from FEEDBACK
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to be certain is to try each method with the relevant data - I suggest using `not exists`:

```
select * from EMPLOYEE e 
where not exists
(select null from FEEDBACK f where e.EMPLOYEE_ID = f.EMPLOYEE_ID)
```